# Store all possible combinations of a specific number range

Tags: mysql, node.js

Supposing I have 1000 numbers from 1 -> 1000, and a user can have any of the 1000 combination (eg: 4, 25, 353..).
How can I efficiently store that combination in a MySQL DB.

What I thought. I can use the power of 2, and store each number in a really large int, like:

1 -> 01

2 -> 10

4 -> 100

etc.

So if I happen to get the number 6 (110) I know the user has the combination of numbers 2, 4 (2 | 4 = 6) .
So we can have 2^1000 combinations, 125byte. But that is not efficient at all since bigint has 8bytes and I cant store 
that in MySQL without using vachars etc. Nodejs cant handle that big number either (and I dont as well) with 2^53-1 being the max.

Why I am asking this question; <s>can I do the above with base 10 instead of 2 and minimize the max bytes that the int can be.</s> That was silly and I think making it to base10 or another base out of 2 changes nothing.

**Edit:** Additional thoughts;

So one possible solution is to make them in sets of 16digit numbers then convert them to strings concat them with a delimiter, and store that instead of numbers. (Potentially replace multiple 1's or 0's with a certain character to make it even smaller. Though I have a feeling that falls into the compression fields, but nothing better has come to my mind.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question I am assuming you are optimizing for space

If most users have many numbers from the set then 125 bytes the way you described is the best you can do. You can store that in a `BINARY(125)` column though. In Node.js you could just a Buffer (you could use a plain string but *should* use a Buffer) to operate on the 125 byte bit-field.

If most users have only a few elements in the set then it will take less space to have a separate table with two columns such as:

```
user_id | has_element (SMALLINT)
---------------------
      1 | 4
      1 | 25
      1 | 353
      2 | 7
      2 | 25
      2 | 512
      2 | 756
      2 | 877
```

This will also make queries cleaner and more efficient for doing simple queries like `SELECT user_id FROM user_elements WHERE has_element = 25;`. You should probably add an index on `has_element` if you do queries like that to make them many times more efficient than storing a bitfield in a column.

Comment: The funny thing is I was originally thinking of creating a new table with a foreign key to the users and an element (the item they have) but that could end up for 1000 users to 1000 * 1000 = 1.000.000 rows. I was trying to avoid that the whole time. So while it is indeed a valid solution I dont know how much more efficient it is. Realistically it will end up being 1.000.000 rows for ~5k users.

Comment: @JohnJames It will ultimately depend on whether you want to do queries that select or JOIN based on which elements a user has in their set. If you do that it will be much *much* more efficient for performance to use a separate table. If you are only worried about space, each SMALLINT is 2 bytes so assuming user_id is 4, it would take less space your average user has less than `125/6 = 20.83` elements in the set.

Comment: If the average number of elements your users have is closer to 200 as your comment suggests, then the BINARY(125) is more efficient for space but still many time less efficient for performance of queries on that column, especially with an index on `has_element`. 1M rows is nothing for MySQL :)

Comment: Yeah indeed, you are right, I was probably wasting my time trying to find something more efficient. Well maybe I just needed to hear it from someone else as well, I'll go with the new table solution so I'll accept your answer :).